Increasing triplet subsequence - does this solution really work, and why?
I've been struggling with the LeetCode problem 334. Increasing Triplet Subsequence:

Given an integer array nums, return true if there exists a triple of indices (i, j, k) such that i < j < k and nums[i] < nums[j] < nums[k]. If no such indices exists, return false.
[...]
Follow up: Could you implement a solution that runs in O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity?

So the numbers need not be consecutive, but their indexes need to be ordered; That is, [1,2,0,3] is true since [1,2,3] works, but [3,2,1] is false.
After finding a good enough solution to pass the tests and reading the accepted solutions, I see the accepted most effective solution is some variation of this:
var increasingTriplet = function (nums) {
    let a = Infinity, b = Infinity, c = Infinity;

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] <= a) a = nums[i];
        else if (nums[i] <= b) b = nums[i];
        else if (nums[i] <= c) {
            return true;
        }        
    }
    return false;
}

And while it does pass the test cases, I'm not certain it's correct. Here's why: Consider the array [20, 100, 10, 12, 5, 13].
The result should be true for that input, since [10, 12, 13] satisfies the condition.
The algorithm does indeed return true for that test, but if we log the values of a, b,and c at the time of succeeding, they are { a: 5, b: 12, c: 13 }, which is not a correct solution because those three numbers are unordered in the original array.
One of two possible things is happening:

The algorithm is wrong.
The algorithm only verifies the existence of the required subset, but it doesn't really find it.

I suspect it's the latter, since I can't manage to build a test case where the algorithm gives a wrong result. However, I can't understand the intuition behind why it's guaranteed to be correct in cases like the one I exposed. I also wonder whether an algorithm that does return a correct subset could work in O(n) time and O(1) space.

What coding language?  Please tag.

Your second bullet is correct.

The solution code you have found is correct. The intuition behind it is that if b is set to some value from the input array, then you know that there was a previous value that was less and that was assigned to a.
If later on a gets a lesser value, this does not change the fact that the current b value still is proof of a lesser value that occurred before it -- we just don't have it stored in a anymore.
If in that state we find a value that is greater than b, we have proof there is an increasing triplet. It doesn't matter that we may not have a reference anymore to the first value in that triplet. The fact we have the second one of that triplet is enough as proof.
Remark on the code
The code does not really need the c variable as it is always Infinity and never gets updated to anything else. The final else doesn't need an if chained to it.
Getting an increasing triplet
If you want to return an increasing triplet instead of just true, then when you find a lesser value for a, don't store it in a yet, but in a temporary "buffer" for it (call it newA or something similar). Only if after that you can improve the value for b, make that value for a permanent by copying it from the "buffer" (newA) to a. Then in the final else, you can ignore whatever there might be in newA, as it might not yet have been made "permanent" by a following new value for b, and so [a, b, last value] will represent the increasing triplet.
Not essential, but in JavaScript this old-style for loop can be rewritten with a for..of loop so you don't need to use indexing with i.
Here is how that looks:


var increasingTriplet = function (nums) {
    let newA = Infinity, a = Infinity, b = Infinity;

    for (const num of nums) {
        if (num <= newA) {
            newA = num; // Don't overwrite `a` yet...
        } else if (num <= b) {
            a = newA; // Now it is safe to overwrite `a`!
            b = num;
        } else {
            return [a, b, num];
        }        
    }
    return null;
}

const nums = [20, 100, 10, 12, 5, 13];
const triplet = increasingTriplet(nums);
console.log(triplet);




So, if A is the set that contains all values taken by a during the algorithm, are we guaranteed an existing solution of the format (x, b, c), with x∈A? (I'm trying to figure out wether this algorithm can be modified to provide the solution without significant increase in time/space).

Yes. See addition to my answer with code to get an actual triplet instead of just true.

Note: real value for b guarantees that smaller value was met before this 'b'. Value for a might be replaced by latter smaller one, but this action does not change the fact of existence  of correct subsequence older_a, b
